# Finding non-matching data in two tables as per columns and arranging column data as row by row

Tags: sql

i have a requirement like below
i have two tables in same data base, both table have same structure and column count.but the columns not present in the same position.
ex:

table 1

```
   id   name      age
   1    dhileep    22
   2    uday       33
```

table 2

```
       id  age      name
       1   20      udayga
       2   22      uday
```

i have id column is same for all tables, if i change the table also i have id same, but may columns name and column count and data count will change.

my final output is:

```
column_name id    table1        table 2
name         1   dhileep        udayga
```

note: i gave above as example, the count of columns is more than 500 and data exist approximately 50000+

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: sorry for the caps lock, i am using SQL..

Comment: Again: "SQL" is just a **query language**, not the name of a specific database product

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2 , but you quite miss understand my question.
please see my final answer i posted.

Comment: i will explain again...i have two tables with exact layout, unfortunately index position is not same. i need to map as per Id column in both table. if data is not matching as per id with as per columns i need to display like column name , id, table1 data , table2 data...like this..

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

use  Sql JOIN .to join the 2 tables

use the following answer .i think it is useful for u.

```
SELECT  t1.id,t1.name,t2.name FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2  AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```